# Find Quarter & Year from File Name using Powershell

Tags: powershell, batch-file

Edited Question.

I am writing a batch script where a file contains a Name and Date in File Name.
So I am extracting date in ADATE variable

```
for /D %%d in ("C:\AA\*") do (
for %%a in ("%%d\*.*") do (SET "FPath=%%~dpa"
Set "FName=%%~na" )
)
::echo %FPath%/%FName%
::timeout 4

For /F "Tokens=4-9 Delims=-" %%A In ("%FName%") Do (
    Set "Freq=%%B"
    Set "ADate=%%F%%E%%D"
)
```

ADate is populating correctly.

```
Set "DFormat=ddMMyyyy"

For /F UseBackQ %%A In (
    `Powershell "([datetime]::ParseExact('%ADate%','%DFormat%', [System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::CurrentCulture)).AddMonths(-1).ToString('MMM-yyyy')"`
) Do Set "DateF=%%A"
```

Above logic is working fine.

But Now I want to fetch Quarter instead of Month-Year.
So Folder name will be Q1-2017, Q2-2017 etc.(Date available in file name subtract 1 quarter)

Can some one tell me how to get this
I was trying below logic.

```
`Powershell "([datetime]::ParseExact('%ADate%','%DFormat%',[System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::CurrentCulture)).AddQuarter(-1).ToString('M')"`
```

Comment: @Mark- The link which your marked is bit different and here I am using Date from File name not from Systemdate.

Answer (score 1):

The `DateTime` struct has no concept or a "quarter", but it's pretty easy to calculate - add `1` to the month, divide by 3, then cast to an integer and rounding will take care of the rest:

```
$DateTime = [datetime]::ParseExact('01042017','ddMMyyyy',[System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::CurrentCulture)
$Quarter = [int](($dateTime.Month + 1) / 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [-f operator](https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-f-operator.html) and wrapped in a batch

```
:: Q:\Test\2017\09\20\SO_46323005.cmd
@Echo off
For /F "Delims=" %%A in (
    'powershell -nop -c "\"Q{0}-{1}\" -f [Math]::ceiling((Get-date -f MM)/3), $(Get-date -f yyyy) "'
) Do Set "Folder=%%A"
Set Folder
Goto :Eof
```

Sample output

```
> SO_46323005.cmd
Folder=Q3-2017
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. but I guess this logic is working on System Date. but in my case I have to use date present in File Name also need to subtract 1 quarter from that. Editing Question please read once.